# (JIT) Compilation of Python code with FFI library calls

Tags: python, performance, jit, numba

I'm using Python with a library that uses `cppyy` to get access to a ton of C++ functions natively in Python. However, the calls to `cppyy` methods take a lot of time, and looping in Python with a library call means that overhead becomes a serious issue. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
import ROOT  # Library based on cppyy

def some_function():
    for i in range(10_000_000):
        ROOT.some_method(i)  # A little bit of overhead * 10_000_000 is a lot of overhead
```

This code would be really fast if I was using the ROOT library directly in C++, but Python is really slow.

Is there a way to JIT compile this to run quickly, where the compiled version doesn't use the Python runtime (like `numba` `nopython=True`)?

Comment: Are you sure that this simple loop is the performance bottleneck? Anyway, did you try to use `numba`? It might also be possible to extract the actuall function pointer from the `cppyy` wrapper, create a `ctypes` function which is then intergrated by `numba` if `numba` can do it itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will have to be very little work done in `some_method` for the cppyy overhead to matter ... Note that there is also the overhead of the method lookup (i.e. the `ROOT.` bit) and the iterator protocol in Python itself isn't negligible either if cppyy overhead isn't (timing an empty loop, I find it's 20% of the total overhead right there).

To avoid all that if this is a tight inner loop, just invert it and run it in C++. E.g. compare these:

```
import cppyy
import time

N = 10000000

cppyy.cppdef("""\
void cppmethod(int i) {
   /* empty */
}""")

f = cppyy.gbl.cppmethod

ts = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(N):
    f(i)
te = time.perf_counter()-ts
print("python loop:", te)

cppyy.cppdef("""\
template<typename T>
void call_cppmethod(T f, int N) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) f(i);
}""")

ts = time.perf_counter()
cppyy.gbl.call_cppmethod(f, N)
te = time.perf_counter()-ts
print("callback loop:", te)
```

On my laptop the callback is 100x faster than the Python loop. However, if I do something in `cppmethod`, eg. calling a trigonometric function, the difference already drops down to 10x (with, again, a good chunk being just the python loop).

Just to be sure, the above use of a template for the callback works in cppyy proper. ROOT, however, contains a *fork* of cppyy that is quite out of date. There you can't use the template and will have to be explicit about the function type:

```
cppyy.cppdef("""\
void call_cppmethod(void (*f)(int), int N) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) f(i);
}""")
```

Likely that problem will go away at some point in the future if/when ROOT updates their fork, but for now it is what it is.